# Send HttpWebRequest to login on a website

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, httpwebrequest

Currently I'm building (trying to) an Android App, in C#, using Xamarin.

it is a simple app the logs into a website, retrieves some data from this website and displays on screen.

So far I've only done other way simpler algoritms, and I'm having trouble in sending the "POST" request to login on the website.

The only information I have from the site is the html forms on it, and I think it is what I need but I'm not sure how to create the HttpWebRequest based only in this:

```
<form name=form_login method=post action=valida.php role=form>
<fieldset>
<h1>QrCafé</h1>
<hr class=colorgraph>
<div class=form-group>
<input name=email type=email id=user_id class="form-control input-lg" 
placeholder=E-mail required>
</div>
<div class=form-group>
<input type=password name=senha id=password class="form-control input-lg" 
placeholder=Senha required>
</div>
```

I know that I have to do the POST to send the username and password (which I'm capturing from the user in a variable, I'm just not really sure how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "hostUrl", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to avoid code-only answers. See if you can edit your answer to include an explanation of how this solves the problem and how OP can use this code format in conjunction with the HTML included in their question.

Comment: I'm not actually sure how to use this.

Comment: I'm trying to use RestSharp  right now, after finding some info on it.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that I have to do the POST to send the username and password (which I'm capturing from the user in a variable, I'm just not really sure how to do it.

First of all, I suggest you using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to trace the headers and post data that is necessary for your request.

Then you can conduct a post request in C# like below:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://mywebsite.com/valid.php");
req.Method = "POST";
//url encoding
string postData=WebUtility.UrlEncode("email=xiaxucheng@126.com&password=hudiai13");
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

//conduct the request headers
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

//conduct the post data
Stream dataStream = req.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();

//get the response
WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
```